# Command line args with getopt not working properly

Tags: linux, bash, getopt, sh

I'm testing getopt for my bourne script and I'm finding some very interesting results.

```
#!/bin/sh

params=$(getopt lLo:p:t: "$*")
exit 0
```

If I do the following:

```
./myscript -z blah -o legal -p another_legal
```

As expected I will get:

```
getopt: illegal option -- z
getopt: illegal option --
getopt: illegal option -- b
getopt: illegal option -- l
getopt: illegal option -- a
getopt: illegal option -- h
```

But if I do this:

```
./myscript -o legal -p another_legal -z blah
```

`getopt` does not catch this.  Any ideas why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"$*"` passes all arguments your function received as a single argument to `getopt`. So you're essentially running `getopt lLo:p:t: "-o legal -p another..."`You want `"$@"` instead.